# Input cap of power amp affecting power supply loop compensation?

Tags: amplifier, boost

I have a TPA3221 power amplifier powered by a TPS55340 30V Boost converter. The boost converter datasheet provides very a specific formula for calculating the loop compensation parameters, based on the "equivalent output capacitance" and the "equivalent load resistance".

The power amp specifies very large input capacitors in its datasheet (470uF or higher).

How can I reconcile these two concerns? Do I need to include the amplifier's input capacitor as part of the boost converter's "equivalent output capacitance"? And how do I calculate the "equivalent load resistance" of a highly complicated amplifier IC?

Is this a situation where one simply has to guess and check? Are there any rules of thumb to follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never have to just guess and check.  Or at least, you can make educated guesses, and then carefully simulate.

You can estimate the input impedance of the TPA3221 by observing two things: first, it's a switching amplifier, so power in = (power out)/efficiency; and second, it's got those great big input caps.

So, let \$\eta = 0.9\$ be the efficiency.  Then \$P_{in} = \frac{P_{out}}{\eta}\$.  For any given power level, if you ignore the capacitor, \$V_{in} i_{in} = P_{in}\$.  Do a bit of math, and you get \$i_{in} = \frac{P_in}{V_{in}}\$.

This is a nonlinear equation, so linearize it around some operating point.  Call it \$V_0 = 30\mathrm{V}\$: $$i_{in}\left(V_{in}\right) \simeq \frac{P_{in}}{V_0} + \left(V_{in}-V_0\right) \left . \frac{d}{dt} \frac{P_in}{V_{in}} \right |_{V_{in} = V_0}$$
This gives you an effective input impedance of \$R_{in} = \left . \frac{d}{dt} \frac{P_{in}}{V_{in}} \right |_{V_{in} = V_0} = -\frac{P_{in}}{V_0^2}\$.  Note the negative resistance -- this will not help stability.

With the cap in parallel smoothing things out, you can use the *average* output power to calculate \$P_{in}\$.  The worst-case negative resistance will be at the highest power output.

On the supply side, if I didn't want to actually do the math to calculate the output impedance of the switching stage, I'd simulate it with a current source as a load.  I'd use a source that's drawing the correct DC current to make \$P_{in}\$ to the following stage correct, and I'd add a sinusoidal current (less than 10% of the standing DC current) to it.  Then I'd look at the sinusoidal component of the resulting output voltage.  Do this for a few frequency points, and you should be able to get a model of the output impedance of the power supply stage.

As long as the sum of the parallel equivalent conductances of the power supply and the load is positive at all frequencies, then the result should be stable.

As an alternative to calculating the output impedance of the power supply, you could make a constant-power load in SPICE using a dependent source.  Put it in parallel with those \$470\mu\mathrm{F}\$ caps, then just simulate your system and look for signs of instability.  You'll need to make your load in a way that it'll allow the supply to start -- you probably want to have it be constant-power up to some maximum current, so it's not trying to draw infinite current at zero volts.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Would the DAC also have an equivalent capacitance/reactance that I would need to also calculate (aside from the large capacitor at the input)?

Comment: Sorry I meant amp, not DAC

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'll want to look at the loop compensation and see if the load is making it unstable. This is best done with a spice package, or you might be able to get TI's tool to give you the loop compensation. Here it is for the TPS55340 with a regular load:

[image]
Source: https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator/customize/3